# Error importing numpy even though I installed it properly

Tags: python, windows, numpy, failed-installation, algorithmic-trading

I am using a module called investpy, and numpy is a dependency of it. I tried running pip install investpy, which installed all of the dependencies (or so it says). However, when I try running

```
import numpy
```

or

```
import investpy
```

, I am faced with this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kakor\OneDrive\Desktop\ML\numpy\__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.__config__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kakor\OneDrive\Desktop\ML\stockscreener.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\kakor\OneDrive\Desktop\ML\numpy\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
```

I'm really confused as to why this is happening, because as far as I know, I correctly installed numpy. Furthermore, this is really weird because, if I go to the python directory in cmd and run import numpy, it works perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you delete the numpy folder?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially numpy seems to complain that it isn't being imported from a standard path.
It looks like you installed numpy directly into your project directory under `C:\Users\kakor\OneDrive\Desktop\ML\numpy` You should remove that directory and try running

`pip install numpy`

Comment: I checked, and numpy is installed into the proper site packages folder. However, python for some reason doesn't recognize modules unless they are installed into the project directory as well as the proper folder. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: You shouldn't have to install anything into the project directory! So you are saying, when you have numpy installed normally and try iporting it with  `import numpy`, it is not importing?  Be careful, this sounds like a typical XY problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: That used to be the problem, but I reinstalled Python today and I thought the problem still existed. After you commented, I rechecked if it works or not, and it worked perfectly. Thank you!